# Angular server side rendering vs maven package single as single jar

Tags: spring-boot, maven-plugin, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Please i would like to know if there is a difference between **Angular universal server side rendering** app with a Spring Boot backend and deploy **Angular + Spring Boot app as single deployment** unit with maven ressource plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server side rendering means that when you load the page in your browser, the server's response will already contains rendered html for that page (components, styles,...). This is especially useful for SEO and speed

The other solution will just deploy angular as a front end app, meaning that the server response will just contain angular scripts, which will render the html only in the browser when the page loads (so no SEO benefits here)